# Only 1 adsense out of 3 is displayed on a page

Tags: google-adsense

I am displaying Google ads on a [page](https://ligatures.net/content/expertise/introduction-to-seo-concepts.html), but for some unknown reason, only one ad out of three is displayed.

Yet the page source code seems correct:

```
<head>
...
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:160px;height:600px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-5587250433868840" data-ad-slot="9807209562"></ins>
    <ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:160px;height:600px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-5587250433868840" data-ad-slot="9020403160"></ins>
    <ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:160px;height:600px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-5587250433868840" data-ad-slot="2834268762"></ins>
    <script>
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>   
    ...
</body>
```

What am I doing wrong? There is no related messages in the Chrome console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ad code you pasted is incomplete - only slot `9807209562` (first one) will be parsed, because there is only one `adsbygoogle.push()`.

Copy/paste code from https://www.google.com/adsense again (preferably [without any modification](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1354736?hl=en) / "optimization") and you should see all three ads are working fine.

If you want to learn more about how asynchronous AdSense code works, please see [An async script for AdSense tagging](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2013/07/an-async-script-for-adsense-tagging.html) post on Google Developers Blog.